# How to combine 2 rsync outputs into 1 command?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, bash-scripting, kubuntu

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`

```
   OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64  
Shell: bash 5.1.16
```

`rsync --version`

```
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
```

variables, SourceDisK1 `src1` and destination `des1`:

```
src1=` cat /tmp/01/sdk1_usb_disk ` 
des1='/media/u3/A1000G/Data/backupUSB2'
```

command1:
`time rsync -ah --delete-before --no-perms --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$des1" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l'`

command1_output with 2 files updated `b.sh` & `c.txt` :

```
        165.07K   0%  126.17MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=593/602)
2023/09/27 21:44:10 >f.st...... 22f876f17e77fb91281260a65f457f3b 165133 b.sh 165070
2023/09/27 21:44:10 .d..t......                                  0 Misc/ 8192
        165.85K   0%   25.38MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=215/602)
2023/09/27 21:44:10 >f.st...... 82dd3c8f657dee803b755955c146816c 827 Misc/c.txt 784
        165.85K   0%   10.58MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/602)  

real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.018s
```

.

command2:

`numfiles=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --log-file=/tmp/1.log --progress "$src1/"   "$des1" |awk '/Number of regular files transferred:/{print $NF}') ;`
`echo $numfiles "regular files transferred"`

command2_output:
`2 regular files transferred`

Question:
In bash, how to issue one (1) rsync command and
get both above outputs `1` and `2`?
example:

```
        165.07K   0%  126.17MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=593/602)
2023/09/27 21:44:10 >f.st...... 22f876f17e77fb91281260a65f457f3b 165133 b.sh 165070
2023/09/27 21:44:10 .d..t......                                  0 Misc/ 8192
        165.85K   0%   25.38MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=215/602)
2023/09/27 21:44:10 >f.st...... 82dd3c8f657dee803b755955c146816c 827 Misc/c.txt 784
        165.85K   0%   10.58MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/602)  

real    0m0.108s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.018s

2 regular files transferred
```

--

Comment: What are the contents of `/tmp/01/sdk1_usb_disk`? Is that a single path?

Comment: contents of ```/tmp/01/sdk1_usb_disk``` is a single path.  
Like ```/media/x_/U_9G_D_VFAT``` for Usb=disk, 9GB, PartitionType=Dos, FileSystemTYPE=vfat, 
from ```lsblk -ae7 -oType,name,path,size,fsuse%,tran,pttype,fstype,label,partlabel,mountpoints |grep 'MOUNT\|nvme\|sd' ```